# Gradle multiproject, multiple root projects and dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is it possible to reference (include) another gradle root project and its subprojects from my main root project?

*Example:* I currently have 2 gradle android multiprojects like this:

```
    rootA
        |--- android_lib_A1
        |--- android_lib_A2
        |--- androidapp_A

    rootB
        |--- android_lib_B1
        |--- android_lib_B2
        |--- androidapp_B
```

How can I properly include gradle project `android_lib_B1` into `rootA` to use it in `androidapp_A` ?

The issues I currently face are the following:

- `rootB` gradle build is not read when included into `rootA`, more
  specifically `allprojects{}`, `subprojects{}` directives
- `rootB` gradle settings is not read which fails the build when
  `android_lib_B1` depends on `android_lib_B2` for example, but this seems to be the normal behaviour according to what I have read.

I can make it work by publishing `android_lib_B1` into my local maven repository, but I'd like to be able to compile it all together, without the extra publishing task.

I have seen that gradle's `ProjectDescriptor` has `parent` and `children` attributes, is this the way to go ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can link an external module in your project using

1) In your project `rootA/settings.gradle`

```
include ':android_lib_A1',':android_lib_A2',':androidapp_A' ':android_lib_B1'
project(':android_lib_B1').projectDir = new File("/path-to-project/rootB/android_lib_B1")
```

2) Add dependency in `build.gradle` of `androidapp_A` module

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':android_lib_B1')
}
```

Pay attention.
In this way you will be able to read the `build.gradle` in the `android_lib_B1` but not the script in rootB.  It means that if you have some tasks or functions defined in the rootB you have to add in the rootA or inside the `android_lib_B1/build.gradle` file.
Of course the `rootB/settings.gradle` will not be read since you are using the rootA project.

A partial solution could be to use a **common folder** where you can put your gradle files.
You can link these files using:

```
apply from: 'gradleFolderScript/myFile.gradle'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried this and as you say my `rootB` tasks are not read. I come from Maven and used `rootB` to factorize the common tasks among my libraries like a parent `pom.xml`. Is there really no other way than to push the conf down to each library? Or copy/paste `rootB` into `rootA`?

Comment: @IppX I don't know it. Usually I use a separate gradle file (not the top level) linking it with `apply from: 'gradleFolderScript/myFile.gradle'`. In this way you could use a common folder to reuse the same gradle files.

Comment: Short answer parsed out of this: No, you can't. But you can re-declare `rootB` config in `rootA` or apply it to both `rootA` and `rootB` from an external file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to keep the projects separate and publish the artifacts to a common repository (eg [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti)). See [publishing artifacts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works indeed, but as I said I would like to avoid this extra publishing task if possible.

Comment: Ah, then @GabrieleMariotti's suggestion of a multi-module build plus `project(...)` dependencies is the solution